# Are there any group queue restrictions in competitive?

Tags: overwatch, competitive-gaming

Games like CS:GO have restrictions on who can queue together, such as a Silver 1 (lowest rank) not being able to queue with a Global Elite (highest rank). Now that players have a number rank up to 100, is there anything stopping a level 1 and a level 100 from queuing together? Or is it allowed and a 1 and 100 just have to be queuing together on the enemy team as well?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any restrictions. At least there were none listed in the [official announcement](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20167051).

Comment: There was mention of being unable to queue with someone if your ratings were more than 50 points apart. I'll try and dig up the source then add it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

In order to queue with friends, there are certain criteria:

- You must be at least level 25.
- Your account must not be banned.
- You must be within 50 Skill Rating of your friends.  Skill Rating is a 100 point scale, and your initial rating is determined by 10 Placement matches at the beginning of each season.

[Source](http://www.overpwn.com/news/190-overwatch-ptr-patch-competitive-season-1-golden)

Answer (score 9):

For Overwatch Competitive Play, as of [Season 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twOXy.png):

- For Bronze through Diamond ranks players must have a skill rating within 1000
- For Master and Grandmaster ranks players must have a skill rating within 500

Ranking groups are provided in the chart below

[image]